# Ruby on Rails Thread Safe Class Variable for Webservice access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, model-view-controller, concurrency

I have a system where, depending on the logged in user i need to set some class variables because the database table names changes for each one, and the key to communicate with the webserver changes to, it is the user document.

I user class variables, like globals, is it thread safe? any chance to save things on the wrong place with many users using the system?

I just set the key on the session and fill the Configuracao class

```
def set_variables
    if current_usuario
        session[:seller_document] ||= current_usuario.documento
        Configuracao.logged_in_document = current_usuario.documento
    end
end
```

Comment: Configuracao.logged_in_document could be thread unsafe - depends on how you have implemented it

Comment: this is just a setter/getter for a class variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a class variable in this manner is not threadsafe. You could use a thread local (ie `Thread.current[:some_key])` , but in general this feels like a design smell to me.

Comment: the problem is , for each select on the database, i need to set an enterprise code, each table has it, its a legacy system integration... i have to set it class level in every request.

Comment: i found this github.com/steveklabnik/request_store maybe it could solve this ? its close from your solution, maybe it is even a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

For thread safety you need to not use class variables.

The session object is a cookie and therefore is specific to only one specific 'user' in one specific session if cookies are cleared out by the user after every visit. So another application accessing your site and using it as a web service will get the cookie.

Normally in an application before filter you would log in the 'user' and set up the session with the users credentials and as such you would expect the application accessing your services to 'log in' by providing authentication credentials. This might be a good place to ensure that the seller_document is always set.

There is no issue with multi threading here as you are not specifically forking processes.

It is perfectly normal for a Rails application to be a web service You are doing everything that rails is intended to do without needing any special consideration over and above the normal security and development considerations needed for a standard Rails application.

Comment: i found this https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store maybe it could solve this ?